# How the data channel of a ftp is working ?

Tags: c, sockets, ftp

I am trying to implement a basic ftp server.

I know that the data channel is created by the PASV command and that it creates a new socket that is used to send data like files.

I started to implement the command LIST, but I don't understand why should I close my data socket when the transfer finished. The ftp client that I am using for my test close his connection with my data socket when he receive the code 226.

That means that the client should do a `PASV` before every commands that require the data channel ?

My code looks like this at the moment :

```
int     list(char **arg, int c_sock, t_data *data)
{
  FILE      *fp;
  char      path[1035];

  write_to_client(c_sock, "150 ", "sending data...\r\n");
  fp = popen("/bin/ls /home/login -l", "r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    {
      printf("Failed to run command\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL)
    {
      write_to_client(data->data_sock, path, "\0");
    }
  pclose(fp);
  write_to_client(c_sock, "226 ", "data send\r\n");
  close(data->data_sock);
  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you need to close the data socket because this is mandated by FTP protocol. FTP protocol says that the data transfer is finished when the socket is closed, and yes, new connection should be created for every data transfer.

It doesn't mean client has to repeat PASV (or PORT in active mode) command for every transfer, though - as long as the listening socket port remains valid, it can be reused.

Comment: Technically, the [official FTP spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc959) states that closing the data socket to indicate EOF is only necessary when the data is being transferred using file structure in stream mode (the default combination). Other combinations of structure modes (record, page) and transmission modes (block, compressed) use explicit EOF indicators on the data connection, thus allowing the same data connection to be reused for multiple transfers. It is not a common practice to use these other modes in modern systems, but they are still part of the official protocol nonetheless.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, interesting. Last time I looked into RFC was more than ten years ago, and I didn't know about that feature. My FTP client did not support it.